# Command to know if offset kafka was reseted

Tags: command-line, apache-kafka

Recently I had the name of my topic changed and then it seems that my consumer read all the messages from the topic, ignoring the offset. I wonder if anyone knows a command that I can check if my offset has been reset?

Thanks
Marcus

Comment: If the topic name changed, then it's new data and new offsets... Nothing was "reset"

Answer (score 0):

In kafka version 2+

If you describe your consumer group to can see the offset:

```
kafka-consumer-groups  --describe --group <consumer group name> --bootstrap-server <kafka broker IP>:9092
```

To change offset to latest:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafka broker IP>:9092 --group <consumer group name> --topic <Topic name> --reset-offsets --to-latest --execute
```

Based on your kafka consumer, consumer group have property to read messages from the beginning, from an offset or latest.

Comment: thanks, but I want to know if the offsets were reseted

Comment: reset? If its a new topic name, it will starts from beginning unless you specified the offset manually.